# Why do my debug icons get stroked in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, debugging

Today, Eclipse has decided to stroke out all my debug icons, wherever they are on my screen. See this example :

[image: Strangely, there is a big stroke on my icon]

Why are these icons stroked ?

Has it something to do with the fact that I can no more debug ?

And if so, how to correct that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 'Skip all breakpoints' selected.

The menu item for this is 'Run > Skip all Breakpoints'. There is also a button on the tool bar and in the debug perspective 'Breakpoints' view.